# How to write a service with Visual C++ Express 2008?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, service

The express editions of Visual C++ lack a template for creating Windows services. However, I heard somewhere that it could still be done. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a C/C++ program that uses the [Service Control Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141(VS.85).aspx) API.  Start by looking at OpenSCManager and CreateService and go from there.